# in Java, how to call a POST web service from one project to another

Tags: java, web-services, http-post

i have a WAR project with POST defined as below

```
@Path("block/v0")
public class classname {.....
...
@POST
    @Path("/{xx}/{yy}/{zz}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public BaseResponseTO blockByShortCodeList(@PathParam("xx") String xx, @PathParam("yy") Long yy,
                                               @PathParam("zz") Long zz) {
...
...
}
```

is there any way for me to submit a post request to the above service from a  different class ( from different package)?

Comment: What do you mean by "submit"? Since the class and method are public, you can simply call the method with valid arguments. If you, for whatever reason, want to make an actual HTTP call, you can use a HTTP client. If you are using microprofile, for example, you can use the [microprofile rest client](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client).

Comment: @Turing85 what do i use in the URL? localhost?

Comment: Depends on your setup. If you, for example, deploy on k8s behind a service and you want to hit the same exact pod, then yes, you would use `localhost`. If you want to hit any other pod behind the service, you would hit the service instead.